# Need to simulate notification message using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to show a message at the bottom-right of the page. I searched Google and I got the right code for it but I have some confusion...some please help me to understand.

Here is the code:

```
<a href="#" class="notify">Show Notification</a>
<div id="notify">You are sexy today!</div>

#notify {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: -200px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

$('.notify').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#notify').animate({ bottom: "10px" }, 250);
});

$('#notify').click(function() {
   $(this).animate({ bottom: "-200px" }, 250);
});
```

1. Why is `right` 10px in CSS?
2. Why has `line-height` been set in CSS?
3. What does `animate` do here? If it will increase 10px then how long it will increase?
4. What is the meaning of this line: `$(this).animate({ bottom: "-200px" }, 250);`?

Please help me to understand those above point. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to change theses values to look what they do?

Comment: This is your ***78th*** question, and people are still having to format your code for you. With respect, that's really not okay, you should have had the hang of formatting code about 76 questions back. When you were asking your question, there was this handy **How to Format** box to the right. ***Well worth reading.*** Also refer to the **[?]** button above the text area, which includes lots of other useful information, including this link: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Formatting properly particularly matters in this case, because we've ended up with a mish-mash of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in one block, where presumably they're separate in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ans 1:** it means the notification makes gap with the right edge of browser of `10px`

**Ans 2:** line height for vertical alignment and making gap among lines

**Ans 3:** it will increase the notify box up to `10px` from its hidden positions

**Ans 4:** it means to hide the notify box below the browser like the sunset in the sea water edge

Comment: u said Ans 3: it will increase the notify box up to 10px from its hidden positions. so u r trying to say jquery will execute a loop to push up the div from it's current position to upward untill it's bottom is 10px. am i right?

Answer (score 1):

- `line-height` is for vertical align
- resizing will last 250 ms
- `$(this).animate({ bottom: "-200px" }, 250)` means: the css property bottom set the value -200px and it is last 250ms

Comment: More like it's used to create the illusion of vertically centered text without having to use padding or margins.

Comment: $('#notify').animate({ bottom: "10px" }, 250);
the above line means that it will increase the notify box up to 10px from its hidden positions. 
so jquery will execute a loop to push up the div from it's current position to upward untill it's bottom is not 10px. 
am i right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably to give space between right window & the notification div
2. Like @Artur Keyan said.
3. Animate will place your div at 10px above the bottom of the document in 250 ms
4. It will place your div to its default location (as specified in the css) in 250 ms

Comment: $('#notify').animate({ bottom: "10px" }, 250);
the above line means that it will increase the notify box up to 10px from its hidden positions. 
so jquery will execute a loop to push up the div from it's current position to upward untill it's bottom is not 10px. 
am i right?

Comment: It will simply push the div from its current position until the difference between the bottom of the document & bottom of the div becomes 10px.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer 1 and 2: its simply styling the element. "`right: 10px`" creates a space of 10px to right of the element (thus pushing it left). Lineheight sets the space between lines of text, again styling.

I'd suggest you download [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) so that you can inspect these page elements and fiddle around with them in real time.

Your animate function is called when you click #notify. It will animate the section to be shown in 250 milliseconds and, just like `right` pushed the element left, `bottom` will **push** the element down 200px.

Comment: $('#notify').animate({ bottom: "10px" }, 250);
the above line means that it will increase the notify box up to 10px from its hidden positions. 
so jquery will execute a loop to push up the div from it's current position to upward untill it's bottom is not 10px. 
am i right?

Comment: It will push it up 10px yes but there's no loop involved.